# How to show content of a function in fish?

Tags: fish

In [fishshell](http://fishshell.com/), I can create and save a function very easy, like:

```
function aaa
   echo hello
end

funcsave aaa
```

But how to view the body of the function `aaa` from command line easily? Is there any way other than:

```
echo ~/.config/fish/functions/aaa.fish
```

Comment: FYI fish aliases are functions, so solutions will also work for aliases.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### invoke `functions aaa` on command line

```
username@MacBook-Pro ~> functions aaa
function aaa
    echo hello
end
username@MacBook-Pro ~>
```

#### Some more uses of functions command

```
functions -n
# Displays a list of currently-defined functions

functions -c foo bar
# Copies the 'foo' function to a new function called 'bar'

functions -e bar
# Erases the function `bar`
```

Answer (score 21):

Also, `type aaa` will show you the function definition, with a bit of a preamble:

```
$ type aaa
aaa is a function with definition
function aaa
    echo hello
end
```

Comment: This is even better than `functions aaa` because the output is syntax highlighted!